# How do I add a column to dataframe that sums # of establishments in adjacent counties based on FIPS adjacency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, one called fips_2018. It lists quantity of business by county FIPS codes. The second, called adjacentCounties, lists county FIPS and 1 row for each adjacent county.

My goal is to add a third column to fips_2018 called '# total_est' that sums all counties with their adjacent counties.

Below I have provided examples of the two input tables, fips_2018 and adjacenCounties, and a third showing the end result of fips_2018.

Note:
'FIPS' are strings,
'# of est' are integers
both input tables contain made up values in 2nd column

Thanks for your help!

```
fips_2018 
FIPS | # of est 
01001   17
01003   3
01009   2

adjacentCounties
FIPS | Adj_Fips
01001   01003
01001   01009
01003   01009
01009   01001
01009   01003

fips_2018 End Result
FIPS | # of est. | # total_est
01001         17           22
01003          3            5
01009          2           22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie the numeric data to the country data. It is then grouped and aggregated with the country data. The resulting columns are added to the original data frame.

```
adjacentCountries = adjacentCountries.merge(fips_2018, left_on='Adj_Fips', right_on='FIPS', how='inner')
adjacentCountries = adjacentCountries.groupby('FIPS_x')['# of est'].sum().reset_index()
fips_2018['# total_est'] = fips_2018['# of est'] + adjacentCountries['# of est']

fips_2018
    FIPS    # of est    # total_est
0   1001    17  22
1   1003    3   5
2   1009    2   22
```